# Обработка выходных значений python

Tags: python

Подскажите как вывести в одну строку полученные значения, в моём случае это программа распознания штрих код, у меня на картинке 3 штрих кода, вот мой код:

```
 for obj in decoded_objects:
    values  = obj.data

    value = values.decode('UTF-8')
    print(value)
```

Ответ:

```
MHLJKBK3MPNXB120904S 
sn=MHLJKBK&mtm=20VD003ERU
MHLJKBK
```

Не получается в кортеж или просто через запятую вывести

Comment: Где у вас собственно печать то?

Comment: не добавил, print(value), я думаю суть вопроса не меняет, я пробовал split('n/', '') все равно в 3 строки выводит

Comment: ГДЕ У ВАС ПЕЧАТЬ В КОДЕ? ДОБАВЬТЕ ЕЁ В КОД. Потому что если вы в цикле печатаете - тогда понятно, я ещё один ответ добавил, другой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собирайте результаты в массив и потом печатайте.

```
result = []
for obj in decoded_objects:
    values  = obj.data
    value = values.decode('UTF-8')
    result.append(value)
print(result) # один вариант печати
print(*result, sep=', ') # другой вариант печати
```

Comment: ['MHLJKBK3MPNXB120904S  ']
['MHLJKBK3MPNXB120904S ', sn=MHLJKBK&mtm=20VD003ERU']
['MHLJKBK3MPNXB120904S ', 'sn=MHLJKBK&mtm=20VD003ERU', 'MHLJKBK3MPNXB120904S  '] 3 массива получается, так же с переводом строк

Comment: сорри print не там поставил

Answer (score 0):

В одну строку:

```py
print(*map(lambda x: x.data.decode('UTF-8'), decoded_objects), sep=', ')
```